# Correct way to update a Realm database?

Tags: java, android, database, realm

This is the structure of my Realm database:

```
    public class ARDatabase extends RealmObject
    {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String uid;

    private String namex;
    private String desc;
    private boolean isVideo;
    private boolean isDeleted;
    private String urlImg;
    private String urlApp;
    private int updates;
    private boolean isDownloaded;
    private String location;

    public ARDatabase(){}

    public String getUid()
    {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid)
    {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getNamex()
    {
        return namex;
    }

    public void setNamex(String namex)
    {
        this.namex = namex;
    }

    public String getDesc()
    {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc)
    {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public boolean getIsVideo()
    {
        return isVideo;
    }

    public void setIsVideo(boolean isVideo)
    {
        this.isVideo = isVideo;
    }

    public boolean getIsDeleted()
    {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setIsDeleted(boolean isDeleted)
    {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    public String getUrlImg()
    {
        return urlImg;
    }

    public void setUrlImg(String urlImg)
    {
        this.urlImg = urlImg;
    }

    public String getUrlApp()
    {
        return urlApp;
    }

    public void setUrlApp(String urlApp)
    {
        this.urlApp = urlApp;
    }

    public int getUpdates()
    {
        return updates;
    }

    public void setUpdates(int updates)
    {
        this.updates = updates;
    }

    public boolean getIsDownloaded()
    {
        return isDownloaded;
    }

    public void setIsDownloaded(boolean isDownloaded)
    {
        this.isDownloaded = isDownloaded;
    }

    public String getLocation()
    {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location)
    {
        this.location = location;
    }
    }
```

And I can successfully add objects to the database.
The problem comes when I need to update an object.

This is what I tried:

```
private void downloadUpdateDatabase(String uid,String location_address) throws RealmException
{

    mRealm.beginTransaction();
    ARDatabase db = new ARDatabase();
    db.setUid(uid);
    db.setIsDownloaded(true);
    db.setLocation(location_address);
    mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(db);
    mRealm.commitTransaction();
    Log.e("TAG","DOWNLOAD UPDATE COMPLETED");

}
```

The problem here is when I invoke this method. The mentioned fields get updated, but the not mentioned fields in this method become null or zero.
Of course I can set values for all fields by invoking their setters, however from where I invoke this method, I can't get all the field values.

So, **the Question is**: How do I update my realm database in such a way that the existing fields don't become null ?

P.S.:

> My Realm version is :0.84.1, `compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.84.1'`

Comment: No , When I insert the values, and the log makes it certain the values are properly inserted

Comment: By the way, version `0.84.1` is super, super old. https://realm.io/docs/java/0.84.1/

Comment: which is the latest version ?

Comment: Click the link I provided. Click the big warning message link. Read the latest documentation from http://realm.io

Comment: `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:${currentVersion}"` even from the gradle file from the latest downloaded file this is how the version is specified .  How to get the latest version this way : `compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.84.1'` .

Comment: I do not know what file you downloaded. I am telling you `0.84.1` needs to be the latest version (`2.3.0` as of this comment), which is well addressed in the docs

Comment: That's what I tried first before going with 0.84, `compile 'io.realm:realm-android:2.3.0'`  and Android studio says failed to resolve io.realm:realm android 2.3.0

Comment: Well, I do not know what you are following to use that version, but that is no longer the only step to install Realm for Android. https://realm.io/news/android-installation-change/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the field that are mentioned gets updated, however the fields that are not mentioned in this method becomes null or zero

Well, yes, all fields are their defaults at this point.

```
ARDatabase db = new ARDatabase();
```

Have you tried to query for the current record, then update the fields, then put that object back?

In other words, you have `String uid`, so something like

```
private void downloadUpdateDatabase(String uid,String location_address) throws RealmException
{
    mRealm.beginTransaction();
    ARDatabase db = mRealm.where(ARDatabase.class).equalTo("uid", uid).findFirst();
    db.setIsDownloaded(true);
    db.setLocation(location_address);
    mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(db);
    mRealm.commitTransaction();
}
```

Or, [probably better in async fashion](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#asynchronous-transactions).

```
private void downloadUpdateDatabase(final String uid, final String location_address) throws RealmException
{
    mRealm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            ARDatabase db = realm.where(ARDatabase.class).equalTo("uid", uid).findFirst();
            db.setIsDownloaded(true);
            db.setLocation(location_address);
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // Transaction was a success.
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            // Transaction failed and was automatically canceled.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Would it fix if I declare `db` global in the first place?

Comment: No? Making a `new ARDatabase();`, all the fields in the `RealmObject` are their default values

Comment: This is how I initially create the object and write to it : `ARDatabase db = realm.createObject(ARDatabase.class);` . So would making this global and using this `db` for updates. Would it fix things ? : /

Comment: I don't think a global object is what you want if you actually do want multiple records of `ARDatabase`. I have updated with my suggestion

Comment: The new edit, its a bit confusing now, would be great if you can make a code edit to `downloadUpdateDatabase()` from the question .

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works perfect. Without the help, wouldn't ve given a thought on  `db` .

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
mRealm.beginTransaction();
ARDatabase db = new ARDatabase();
db.setUid(uid);
db.setIsDownloaded(true);
db.setLocation(location_address);
mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(db);
mRealm.commitTransaction();
Log.e("TAG","DOWNLOAD UPDATE COMPLETED");
```

There should be

```
mRealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        ARDatabase db = realm.where(ARDatabase.class).equalTo("uid", uid).findFirst();
        if(db == null) {
            db = realm.createObject(ARDatabase.class, uid);
        }
        db.setIsDownloaded(true);
        db.setLocation(location_address);
    }
});
Log.e("TAG","DOWNLOAD UPDATE COMPLETED");
```